# How to implement Scanning and Transfer data using Bluetooth Beacon (BLE) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, flutter-layout, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to transfer data between two bluetooth devices, How it can be done using Googles Flutter

Comment: Flutter has no built in support for BLE (Flutter is a UI toolkit, not a Bluetooth library). You must either implement a plugin using native code, or use a plugin written by someone else. Recommendations for software libraries is off topic for Stack Overflow since it can result in opinion-based answers.

Comment: You may want to start from [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue). But please do some pre-research, write some code, have some new problems than ask a question in SO.